# Reuse pipe filter result for other element

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

Looking at an example at the [official angular2 pipes documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html), I wonder if it is possible to achieve the following:

```
    <div [hidden]="hasFlyingHeroes">
      <span>Heroes fly!</span>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of (heroes | flyingHeroes)">
      {{hero.name}}
    </div>
```

where "hasFlyingHeroes" uses the filtered value of the ngFor in order not to filter out the flyingHeroes twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes are for sharing the common behaviour between unrelated pieces of data.

The pieces of data with specific behaviour can be represented as models,

```
@Injectable()
class Heroes extends Array {
  getFlying() {
    return this.filter(hero => hero.canFly);
  }

  hasFlying() {
    return !!this.getFlying().length;
  }  
}
```

and

```
<div [hidden]="heroes.hasFlying()">
  <span>Heroes fly!</span>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes.getFlying()">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

For a model that is represented with extended array it is normal to call `getFlying` twice, because it has several ways to be modified, so caching the filtered set won't do anything good.

For a model that is modified strictly through specific public method (e.g. `add`) it is possible to invalidate the cache there and cache the filtered set, `getFlying` will be called only once.